# Prevent auto generated push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging

When we receive a push notification while the application is in the background mode, it automatically uses **aps** and other parameters like **Sound, Badge, Alert** to generate a notification that appears on top.

What I want is to prevent that auto generated notification let it call `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and generate my custom local notification and display it on top and notification centre.

The reason behind this is that the message is customised according to situation which is managed locally after some data received in push notification.

I haven't tried anything, because I couldn't find any solution for this kind of scenario. I don't even know whether it is even possible or not.

Any help or other suggestion that could to solve this other way is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look to iOS Silent Notifications [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html)

But you have 2 differences cases :

- 1 your app is in front, the did receive remote is called, and the notification is not displayed.
- 2 your app is in background, and I don't think the `didreceiveRemove` is called.

So in the 2 situations, you will not achieve your goal. You shroud maybe try to customize the notification before sending it

Comment: Which method gets called if we are using background fetch. Which gives us 30 seconds of time to perform instructions?

Comment: The method `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchHandler:` is called while the app is in the background, if the notification payload contains the value `content-available: 1` in the `aps` dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @Avi. That will help me to generate local notification but bigger problem is to prevent auto generated push notification.

Comment: I think you can't except if your notification is a silent notification. But if you dont have access to server-side code, you just can't to id

Answer (score 0):

Even when your App is in the background, suspended, inactive or terminated it is woken by a Silent push notification. 
(Note: the only scenario when the app is not woken by silent push is when it had been killed off by the user from the control centre)

So you can send a silent push, perform whatever operations you need to perform on the data and then generate a local notification which would go in the tray.